# Project tracker with easiest learning curve

Tags: scrum, agile

Here's the thing. 
Most of my life it was all about Jira. Unfortunately right now I'm working as a agile coach (kinda) in an interactive agency that in terms of project management is still in Stone Age.

I think that Jira might be a little bit too problematic in this situation, especially at this stage - early introduction to scrum.

If you have similar experience and know best soft to use in this case (or maybe assure me that Jira can work), that would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: searching a program or software might be mor successful on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ . If you are looking for a solution to your specific situation, it might help to post some more details, e.g. company size, project duration, current PM processes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your team is all in the same location, then start with a physical board. There is some pretty hard science out now that physical boards are better when you can take advantage of co-location. 
I recently wrote a blog going into more detail on why [physical task boards still matter](http://www.leadingagile.com/2015/05/why-physical-task-boards-still-matter/).

If you have to have an online tool, start with something dirt simple like Trello.com. New toy syndrome often has us jumping for all the bells and whistles. Instead follow the same principles of agile/ lean and go with the absolute minimum functionality to start. See what works and what you really need before going to the bells and whistles.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In fact I already introduced whole team to task boards (firm believer that physical matter beats software anytime). The problem is that at some point amount of projects, team size and outsourcing can bite us, so I want to start with some sort of soft as soon as possible. Trello is actually great suggestion, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem on my last project, where people doesn´t know nothing about project management and nothing about scrum and even nothing about planning.

I started only with some parts of scrum and it´s working very fine. I used:

1. First meetings with stakeholders to define needs and priorities (this happens almost every 2 weeks);
2. Meetings with development team to define the tasks that will need to
   do (this happens every time that we finish last sprint);
3. Planning poker to establish efforts (happens together with the sprint meetings);
4. Kanban board to distribute the tasks;
5. Very quickly daily review of tasks that are ongoing;

I used it as a simple way, not too much information on they´re heads, so, people get involved quickly.

Now they can see what is going on and who is working and who is not;
They are also collaborating as a team on the meetings;

Also, our kanban board is scheduled by date limit (1 week) so we delivery changes, at least, every 1 week. They are happy because project seems to go on and not stucked on some phase that no one knows where.

I think people here are almost ready to grow up to some next level of management.